# How to get a isapi dll physical path from a program in release mode

Tags: c++, isapi

LPTSTR  DLLPath = new TCHAR[_MAX_PATH];
    ::GetModuleFileName((HINSTANCE)&__ImageBase, DLLPath, _MAX_PATH);

I was using the above function to get the  isapi dll physical path. it works fine in debug mode.When i try to build it in release mode it says __ImageBase unidentified .
can anyone suggest me an alternative to this.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should probably cast it like so:

`__ImageBase` is normally the value: `0x400000`, this is normally where the Image Loader, loads the .exe in memory.

```
HINSTANCE hInst = reinterpret_cast<HINSTANCE>(&__ImageBase)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably save and use the `hInstance` parameter passed into `DllMain()` rather than `__ImageBase`.